# Поиск всех строк дубликатов в таблице без первого значения

Tags: sql, запрос

Уважаемые разработчики! Прошу подсказать как доработать следующий запрос:есть нижеприведенная таблица c повторяющимися значениями в полях  `date_time`, `item_id`, `customer_id`.
Требуется найти в ней дубликаты, но только без первой строки, с которой начинаются дубли.

```
select date_time,item_id,customer_id
from Orders
where date_time AND item_id AND customer_id in (
  select date_time,item_id,customer_id
  from orders
  having count(*) > 1
  group by date_time,item_id,customer_id
)
order by date_time,item_id,customer_id;
```

Я так понимаю, что сейчас код выводит все значения, где есть дубли. Как найти дубликаты без первых значений?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *Требуется найти в ней дубликаты* Дубликаты с точки зрения SQL - это точное совпадение значений во всех полях записей. Но при этом весьма странно звучит "первая строка" - ибо нет никакого признака, который позволит одну из записей посчитать первее другой. На позиционность при выводе кивать не надо - это "так получилось", и в любой момент может измениться.

Comment: *Я так понимаю, что сейчас код выводит все значения, где есть дубли.* Нет, сейчас он выводит голимую хрень, преобразуя `date_time` и `item_id` в число и свершая над ними логический `AND`. Если вообще что-то выводит, а не падает по ошибке.

Comment: Да,первая строка звучит странно, скажем, это одна из повторяющихся строк.

Comment: Ммм... можно перефразировать задачу так: для каждой группы дубликатов вывести запись-дубликат в количестве на 1 меньше количества записей в группе? В любом случае - укажите конкретную СУБД, включая точную версию.

Comment: Oracle sql,любой версии

Comment: Хотел бы также спросить, как поправить условие where, чтобы это условие проверялось для 3 столбцов.

Comment: Выложите пример данных в виде CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO скриптов (десяток записей достаточно), и покажите требуемый результат для именно таких данных. Или сразу создайте fiddle, скажем, [тут](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2)

Answer (score 0):

Вы не указали СУБД. Этот код для MS-SQL (T-SQL). Также не понятно определение "без первых значений", по какому признаку в дубликатах выбирать "первое значение"? В данном примере исключается строка с минимальным значением в поле quanity.

```
declare
    @t table (date_time datetime, item_id int, customer_id int, quanity int)
declare
    @dt datetime=getdate()

insert into @t
select @dt, 1,1,100
union all
select @dt, 1,1,200
union all
select @dt, 1,1,300
union all
select @dt, 2,2,100

select * from (
    select *, DENSE_RANK() over (partition by date_time, item_id , customer_id order by quanity)  rnk
    ,count (*) over (partition by date_time, item_id , customer_id order by (select 1)) cnt
    from @t
    )t
where rnk !=1 and cnt>1
```

Comment: А почему `DENSE_RANK`, а не `ROW_NUMBER`? Понятно, что результат одинаковый, но, имхо, номер строки по порядку тут семантически правильнее

Comment: @ГерманБорисов видимо привычка явно ранжировать записи, поэтому на автомате выбрал DENSE_RANK()